# CEF windowless rendering - disable-gpu flag

Tags: c++, windows, chromium-embedded

I am using cef version 2704. OS: Windows 10

In my application, I create 3 browsers (using CefBrowserHost::CreateBrowser).
one of them is rendered with "offscreen rendering".

What I would like to get, is to disable gpu and gpu-compositing (so passing disable-gpu and disable-gpu-compositing switches) within the "offscreen rendering" renderer.
The other two renderers should use th gpu and compositing.

**So my questions: is it possible to have different rendering solutions for different renderers/browsers?**

I know, that I could change/add the passed switches to renderers in

```
CefBrowserProcessHandler::OnBeforeChildProcessLaunch(
    CefRefPtr<CefCommandLine> command_line
)
{
    command_line->AppendSwitch("disable-gpu");
    command_line->AppendSwitch("disable-gpu-compositing");
}
```

However, when I do that for any window (not only the "windowless rendered" one) the window becomes black (rendering breaks).
On the other hand, rendering works (in all the windows) if I add this switch globally to all the renderers here:

```
CefApp::OnBeforeCommandLineProcessing(
    const CefString& process_type, 
    CefRefPtr<CefCommandLine> command_line
)
{
    command_line->AppendSwitch("disable-gpu");
    command_line->AppendSwitch("disable-gpu-compositing");
}
```

But, in such situation, all the browsers don't use gpu. As mentioned above, I want to have it enabled normally, and just disable it for the one browser (with windowless rendering).

Cef Settings I pass to CefInitialize:

```
settings.single_process = false;
settings.multi_threaded_message_loop = false;
settings.no_sandbox = true;
settings.windowless_rendering_enabled = true;
```

CefWindowInfo I am using for offscreen rendering:

```
windowInfo.SetAsChild(windowHandle, rect);
windowInfo.SetAsWindowless(windowHandle, true);
```

CefWindowInfo I am using for standard rendering:

```
windowInfo.SetAsChild(GetSafeHwnd(), rect);
```

Comment: http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=14563#p32511

Comment: Yes, I have also asked on the CEF forum. The answer was, that it is impossible. It is mainly due to Chromium implementation.

Comment: It's standard practice when you ask a question on multiple places to provide links, save the same question being answered twice and so others can find the answers.